# Html Form Not Send Data To PHP Code

Tags: php, html

my html form not sending food val to php to print it on browser
   so i want enter some data into html page and i want the php code print it the value in php code is food !

```
 <?php


    if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
    {   
        echo $food;
    }

    ?>

    <html>
    <form action="" method="get">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="food" value="enter food">
    <br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"></input>
    <input type=reset value="reset">
    </form>
    </html>
```

Comment: value from food field exists in `$_GET['food']`

Comment: I would advise you to use `if( !empty($_GET['food'] )){ ... }` instead. `isset()` only checks if the variable exists. Which always returns true when you submit the form. Even if the food field is empty. `empty()` will also check if something was filled in or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use food $_GET["food"] instead of $food.
Here is code:

```html
    if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
    {   
        echo $_GET['food'];
    }
```

Comment: Tnx But Why i cant just do  <?php echo $food ; ?>

Comment: @teko because $_GET is global variable, that contains variables from GET request.$food is just undefined variable.

Comment: @teko You can't use `$food` because it doesn't exist. By submitting your form, you are creating the `$_GET['food']` variable. So it exists. But you didn't create the `$food` variable. If you want to use that, you have to create it first by doing `$food = $_GET['food']`. Now you have created the `$food` variable and put the value of `$_GET['food']` inside it.

Comment: yeah thanks so much for this info..

Answer (score -1):

`action` should be `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"`

After you do that you can check and access your variables with `$_GET['food']`.

Comment: blank action is fine - that is always submit to self

Comment: Maybe for student projects... you need to filter form inputs on submit otherwise you'll be vulnerable to malicious injections.

Comment: No. You are filtering before submit, i can still submit a form( or make any request) to any url on your site. You filter on receipt of the data.